# How to connect to Oracle ADW instance using dbeaver

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-call-interface, dbeaver

I need to connect to an ADW instance provisioned in my OCI space. The documentation to connect shows me how to connect using wallet credentials, but using sql developer. I am able to connect using SQL developer. But i like dbeaver and I would like to connect to the ADW instance using dbeaver. Please show me how i can do this?

Comment: Follow these instructions for jdbc thin https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-1640CC02-BF3E-48C2-8FFE-A596614A6A40

Comment: and curious - any dbeaver things you like, but find missing in SQL Developer? We're always open to improvements based on user feedback

Comment: thank you sir. i just use dbeaver for connecting to my postgres instance, my redshift instance and didnt want to have to install another tool. sql developer is nice, i have no problems with it :) thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just wanted to add a note here that I use SQL Developer to connect redshift, postgres, ADW, MySQL, Sybase, and SQL Server.

Comment: DBeaver has the best autocomplete for table names and column names, it searches in the middle of names, not just names which start with what you wrote, e.g. usress will provide user_address as well. The autocomplete feature works faster than in other programs and many other things work faster. It has a duplicate row functionality when viewing query results.

Answer (score 3):

- In the DBeaver "Connect to a database" menu, click "Driver Settings".
- Select on the "Libraries" tab.
- Click "Download/Update".
- Clicking on the version number for each file allows you to select another version. Select one higher than 12.2.0.1 (I recommend using the 18.3.0.0)
- Click download to update drivers.
- Go back to the "Connect to a database" menu.
- Choose the "Custom" connection type.
- Enter the jdbc URL with a `TNS_ADMIN` parameter pointing to the location of your wallet.

Example jdbc url:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@YOURDB_high?TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/wallet_YOURDB`

In addition, specify password and username.

Answer (score 1):

- download [oracle drivers with pki](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19-6-c-downloads.html)
- Try also to unpack the wallet.zip. Make the directory of the same name as your wallet and in the same directory as the wallet and put the files from the wallet archive there. I am not sure is this step important but I read somewhere it can help
- create a new oracle connection in DBeaver. Choose "Edit driver settings"
- in "Libraries" tab, remove everything and add the downloaded drivers
- for a "Connection type" choose "Custom"
- in "JDBC URL template" enter something like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection_from_tnsnames?TNS_ADMIN=c:\\location_of_wallet_CVANEDEV`

Here is some info about oracle wallet connections: [JDBC Thin Connections with a Wallet (mTLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-EBBB5D6B-118D-48BD-8D68-A3954EC92D2B)

Comment: Yes, this is function way. But I have one question. How to replace TNS_ADMIN path from static path to variable ${project.path}. Any experience ?

Answer (score 0):

Goto DBeaver New connection Oracle

- Select TNS tab
- Choose your downloaded wallet `tnsnames.ora` file in the `TNS names Path` input, it populates the Network Alias automatically.
- Goto Driver properties tab (Next to Main) in Dbeaver and fill the properties give ojdbc.properties (Available in the Downloaded wallet, Ref : javax.net.ssl.trustStore, javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword, javax.net.ssl.keyStore, javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword)

Make sure `${TNS_ADMIN}` path is valid or change it to an absolute path